# Using MdDialogConfig data on Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, mddialog

I'm trying to use a [dialog component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog) in Angular 2 using `@angular/material2.0.0-beta.1`. What I'm trying to accomplish is to send data (which are values that a person chooses from the interface, the dialog is used to make the person confirm the values they chose) to the dialog and display it. So for example the dialog should say something like this:

You chose:

option 1: value

option 2: value

option 3: value

Cancel | Confirm

How can I pass these values to the dialog I create so that I can just access them like so {{value}} in the view template? I think its using the data config, but I can't seem to find good documentation or examples on how to use it. Here's what I've been trying:

```
let config = new MdDialogConfig().data();
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
```

DialogComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
   selector: 'dialog',
   template: require('./dialog.component.pug'),
   styleUrls: [
     './dialog.component.scss'
   ]
})

export class DialogComponent {
   constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In parent component:

```typescript
const config = new MdDialogConfig();

config.data = [
  // for example:
  'value 1',
  'value 2'
];

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, config);
```

`DialogComponent`:

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef }       from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog',
  template: require('./dialog.component.pug'),
  styleUrls: [
    './dialog.component.scss'
  ]
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  private values;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.values = this.dialogRef.config.data;
  }
}
```

And sample template (HTML version):

```html
<md-dialog-content>
  <md-list *ngIf="values">
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let value of values">{{ value }}</md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</md-dialog-content>
```

### Update — `@angular/material` 2.0.0-beta.3

Since [version 2.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.3) of Angular Material, it is no longer possible to access `config` (and `config.data`) property of `MdDialogRef<T>`. Instead, you should inject `MD_DIALOG_DATA` token to access any data passed into your dialog component.

Imports:

```typescript
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { MD_DIALOG_DATA, MdDialogRef }         from '@angular/material';
```

The constructor:

```typescript
constructor(
  @Optional() @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) private dialogData: any,
  private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>
) {}
```

`ngOnInit` method:

```typescript
ngOnInit(): void {
  // alternatively, rename ‘dialogData’ to ‘values’ and remove the
  // ‘ngOnInit’ method
  this.values = this.dialogData;
}
```

In many cases you’ll need to keep the `@Optional()` decorator, until [issue 4086](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4086) will get resolved.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: Definitely use the above Inject method to get your data. This way is dependent upon accessing a private member which is not guaranteed to remain untouched between versions**

If you're using the new 2.0.0 beta 3 (or maybe it was even changed in beta 2, not sure) then the above answer has to be changed a little bit:

```js
@Component({
selector: "dialog",
templateUrl: "./dialog.component.html"
})
export class DialogComponent {
    constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>) { }
    type: string;
    name: string;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        let configData: any = this.dialogRef._containerInstance.dialogConfig.data;
        this.type = configData.type;
        this.name = configData.name;
   }
}
```

It seems like there should be a better way of referencing the data than `this.dialogRef._containerInstance.dialogConfig.data` but I couldn't find one

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do is to set the values from within the parent component
**DialogComponent**

```
@Component({
selector: "dialog",
templateUrl: "./dialog.component.html"
})
export class DialogComponent {
    constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>) { }
    type: string;
    name: string;
    ngOnInit(): void {

   }
}
```

**ParentComponent**

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
dialogRef.componentInstance.type= title;
dialogRef.componentInstance.name= url;
```