# Passing data to MdDialog no longer works

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to pass data to a dialog but the way it should be done (according to several examples found on the internet, like [Using MdDialogConfig data on Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520269/using-mddialogconfig-data-on-angular-2)) does not work.

I get the following error:

```
 Property 'data' does not exist on type 'MdDialogConfig'
```

When I look at the code of the MdDialogConfig this property indeed does not exists (anymore)

I used the example that can be found as the accepted answer to the topic above, but it doesn't work. The example code being:

```
const config = new MdDialogConfig();

config.data = [
   // for example:
   'value 1',
   'value 2'
];

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, config);
```

Scanning the rest of the code, I see no other way to pass data directly. 
I could fall back to using a separate service to pass data from the component to the dialog but that is far from ideal.

Is there a proper way to pass data to a dialog?

I am using version 2.0.0-beta.1

Comment: I see that there is a newer version available that does seem to have the data propery. Checking it out at this moment

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Unfortunately the api's for including the theme changed also. Making it frustrating to make more changes than I anticipated....

Comment: This is a problem again in 4.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own inflatable Component (note the detail field)

```
export class DialogDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() detail: Detail;

    constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogDetailComponent>) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    close() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

}
export interface Detail { }
```

And create a method that opens that dialog in your Service

```
openDialogDetail(c: Type<DialogDetailComponent>, detail: Detail, afterClosed?: (data?) => any, type?: number, width: string = "80%", height: string = "80%", disableClose = false) {

    let dialogRef = this.openDialog(c, afterClosed, width, height, disableClose);

    if (detail)
        dialogRef.componentInstance.detail = detail;

    return dialogRef;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem I had was that in 2.0.0-beta.1 the data property was not implemented. It turns out that in 2.0.0-beta.2 it is back.

Comment: Glad to hear. However you can use this strategy if you need more flexibility. Bye!