# Get data from md-dialog on Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, mddialog

I am implementing an [md-dialag from Material Design](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog) on my Angular 4 application. I have currently achieved to pass data into the modal, but have not been successful to retrieve any data entered by the user on the dialog.

This is how I open a dialog:

```
ShowAddStop() {
    this.general = {fc: this.locationCtrl, fl: this.filteredLocations, selectedNewStop:this.selectedNewStop};
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogAddStop,{data:this.general});
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

But for instance, on the dialog I have an input field which I want the user to fill:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="ShortName">
```

Where Shortname is a variable on the class from where I called the dialog, it won't change that variable, I think it creates its own scope and that's why it isn't using my class instance variables.

Is there something basic I'm missing on retrieving data back from the dialog?

Comment: How the dialog gets closed?

Comment: like this:
<button md-button md-dialog-close="0">Cancel</button>
<button md-button md-dialog-close="1">Save</button>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, **acquire** a `MdDialogRef<DialogAddStop>` reference and a `MD_DIALOG_DATA` token in the dialog constructor:

```typescript
constructor(
  @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) private dialogData: any,
  private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogAddStop>
) {}
```

See also [Using MdDialogConfig data on Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42533279/7178441) for some explanations regarding `MD_DIALOG_DATA`.

**Create** a `shortName` variable inside the dialog class:

```typescript
public shortName: string
```

**Set** initial value of `shortName` to the one provided by the parent component:

```typescript
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.shortName = this.dialogData['shortName']
}
```

**Create** a “saving” handler:

```typescript
public onSave() {
  this.dialogRef.close(this.shortName)
}
```

**Attach** that handler to the *Save* button:

```html
<button (click)="onSave()" md-button>Save</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do I get that variable on the class from where I called the dialog? (it works inside the dialog onSave() method by the way)

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to `dialogRef.afterClosed()` and reading its result?